# WooCommerce Variable products filter not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to implement product price filters  on WooCommerce website. It works perfectly from simple products but on Variable products it is not working.

For example website has 10 products 5 are simple products and 5 are variable products. But on product price filters it shows  simple products results only.

How can I resolve it for both type of products.

Comment: can you show us what did you try so far ? the code ?

Comment: I did not tried any code, I am using  widget WooCommerce price filter. Which WooCommerce by default provide. I have also tried some plugins like `WooCommerce Products Filter`, `YITH WooCommerce Ajax Product Filter` and some other but none of them worked

Comment: so did your read the documentation ? did you check the FAQ? here we cannot help if you don't know what's the issue and if there is an issue or not ... maybe they are not made to work with variable prices